# Problema con las IPN

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy armando un proyecto en *Laravel 5.4* ya integre el sdk de *mercadopago* y configure la url de notificaciones con un test user.

Para realizar un checkout básico primero creo las preferencias:

```
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => $items,
    "payer" => array(
        "name" => 'TEST_Name',
        "surname" => 'TEST_surname',
        "email" => 'TEST@email.com',
        "phone" => array(
            "number" => 'TEST_351471'
        ),
        "address" => array(
            "zip_code" => 'TEST_zipcode',
            "street_name" => 'TEST_street',
            "street_number" => intval('123')
        )

    ),//TODO Replace hardoced urls
    "notification_url" => /*url*/,
    "auto_return" => "all",
    //TODO remove hardcoded order id.
    "external_reference" => base64_encode(json_encode(['order_id' => '123'])),
);
```

Después instancio un objeto MP y llamo a la función `create_preference()`:

```
$mp = new \MP(Config::get('mpago.client_id'),Config::get('mpago.client_secret'));
$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);

return redirect()->to($preference['response']['sandbox_init_point']);
```

Hasta acá todo va perfecto. Ahora el problema es que cuando mercado pago me notifica pasa lo siguiente:

Apenas inicia el checkout me envía una notificación con los parámetros id y el topic "merchant_order", con esto puedo traer la info tranquilamente pero como el checkout recién empieza no me sirve para nada.

Una ves terminado el proceso de checkout me envía otra notificación pero con los siguientes parámetros:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "3980044"
    },
    "date_created": "2017-06-16T16:34:14.000-04:00",
    "type": "payment",
    "api_version": "v1",
    "id": 170178729,
    "action": "payment.created",
    "user_id": 260874864,
    "live_mode": false,
    "data_id": "3980044"
}
```

Ahora cuando trato de traer el payment_info (probé con sandbox en *true* y *false*) siempre me devuelve **not_found**, ya sea usando el id o el data_id, así que no se como actualizar el estado de mi orden a partir de este punto.

Comment: yo tengo un problema similar. Y estoy seguro que es por el uso del sandbox_init_point. Si esas ese link, la transacción se completa, pero no te la guarda como para despues podes obtenerla.
Si usas en link del init_point, la transacción nunca se completa y queda En Proceso, pero si la guarda y luego la podes obtener. Lo habras solucionado de alguna forma?

Comment: msassa, bienvenido a SOes. Generalmente usamos este espacio para proporcionar respuestas a las preguntas. Si tienes algun otro problema o quieres plantear la pregunta desde tu punto de vista, puedes hacerlo publicando una pregunta nueva, sin ningun problema.

Comment: Si, bueno, mi comentario si bien no tiene una respuesta completa tiene una orientacion a indicar desde donde viene el problema y direccionar mejor la solucion.
De todas formas queria comentar que hoy eso que comento en la respuesta ya no sucede, usando el link init_point la transaccion es aprobada. O sea que me inclino porque el problema es directamente de la api.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto y agradezco la participacion. Solo te invito a verlo desde otro punto de vista. Imagina que alguien mas tiene un problema similar. Al buscar la pregunta, ve que hay una respuesta. Presiona el link y para su sorpresa, la respuesta dada no soluciona el problema, de ninguna forma posible. La persona ha perdido tiempo y StackOverflow, aunque minimo, ha gastado recursos de procesamiento para mostrar la pagina. Ya que nadie te ha cobrado por crear tu cuenta, invitamos a todos a mantener la calidad del sitio aportando respuestas concretas.

Comment: lo pudiste resolver de alguna forma? Porque estoy con el mismo problema y no tengo forma de obtener los datos reales. Gracias.

Comment: @ecgk al final creo que termine usando el init_point de la preference en ves del sandbox_init point. `$preference['response']['init_point']`. y para pagar usas cualquier usuario pero con las tarjetas de prueba https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/test-cards/

Comment: es el Sandbox el problema. A mi me pasó y una vez que me aseguré que todo funcionara mas o menos bien, opté por usar mi tarjeta con la cuenta de marcadopago real, y así de ese modo tengo seguridad de que los datos que trae son los mismos que voy a tener en produccion. Yo usé aproximadamente 7 u 8 pagos de $1 hasta que lo tuve funcionando, asi que no vale la pena usar el sandbox...